# Force CMake to link against static library over dynamic when building lib from subdirectory

Tags: cmake, libcurl, static-linking

I have a CMake project which builds a few other libraries using `add_subdirectory()` and links against them with `target_link_libraries()`. One lib builds only a static library by default and the other is only a header. However, [`curlpp`](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp) builds both a shared and static lib without an `option()` to change that behavior.

When I build my binary and move it to a different system, without curlpp installed, I get an error (`error while loading shared libraries: libcurlpp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`). I would like to force CMake to link against the static version of the library, but so far have failed to do so.

I also tried passing the full path to the static library to `target_link_libraries()`, but that causes a built time error (`No rule to make target 'external/curlpp/libcurlpp.a'`). I assume this approach would work, if the library was already built and installed on the system, but in my case, it's being build at the same time as my code.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(FOO VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX C)
set(TARGET bar)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

configure_file(include/config.hpp.in include/config.hpp)

add_executable(${TARGET} src/main.cpp)
install(TARGETS ${TARGET} DESTINATION bin)

# DOWNLOAD SUBMODULES
find_package(Git QUIET)
if(GIT_FOUND) 
    option(GIT_SUBMODULE "Check submodules during build" ON)
    if(GIT_SUBMODULE)
        message(STATUS "Submodule update")
        execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} submodule update --init --recursive
                        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                        RESULT_VARIABLE GIT_SUBMODULE_RESULT)
        if(NOT GIT_SUBMODULE_RESULT EQUAL "0")
            message(FATAL_ERROR "git submodule update --init --recursive failed with ${GIT_SUBMODULE_RESULT}")
        endif()
    endif()
endif()
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0115 OLD) # Supresses libcoap configuration warning
set(ENABLE_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "Disable libcoap docs, because they break the build")
set(ENABLE_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Disable libcoap examples, we only want the lib")
set(DTLS_BACKEND "openssl" CACHE STRING "Build libcoap against OpenSSL")
set(ENABLE_TCP OFF CACHE BOOL "Disable TCP, we only want UDP support")
add_subdirectory(external/libcoap)
add_subdirectory(external/plog)
add_subdirectory(external/curlpp)

target_include_directories(${TARGET}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC external/libcoap/include
    PUBLIC external/plog/include
    PUBLIC external/curlpp/include
)

target_link_directories(${TARGET}
    PRIVATE  external/libcoap
    PRIVATE  external/curlpp
)

# THIS ENDS UP LINKING AGAINST THE DYNAMIC LIB
target_link_libraries(${TARGET}
    PRIVATE coap-3 curlpp
)

# PASSING THE FULL PATH TO THE STATIC LIBRARY FAILS
# (No rule to make target 'external/curlpp/libcurlpp.a')
# target_link_libraries(${TARGET}
#     PRIVATE coap-3 ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/external/curlpp/libcurlpp.a
# )
```

Comment: "I would like to force CMake to link against the static version of the library" - So link with `curlpp_static`, which is a target representing the static curlpp library.

Comment: Thanks that solves it! Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it as the solution. I'm pretty new to CMake so wasn't aware I could do that

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code you show to a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curlpp` project creates separate **targets** for static and shared libraries:

- `curlpp` target represents the shared library,
- `curlpp_static` target represents the static library.

In `target_link_libraries` call you may use the target which is suitable for your purposes. E.g.

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} curlpp_static)
```

will link with the static curlpp library.